# How can I send text to from one route (/client/1) to another route (/client/2) using ajax in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a simple rails (4) application and realize that I really need to send text to each other who sit on different routes (/client/1 and /client/2) without reloading the page. 
This is what I got so far.

- route (/client/1) 
  there is an input tag and I made this form with rails form helper to send XHR request to the associated controller
- In the controller, I grab the text by params and assigned it to an variable
- I made a js file named after the action and append the variable into a tag

This is working in  client/1 but I cannot figure out how to send the text to another route (/client/2).

Please help me to make this possible.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You need a streaming mechanism.

First, to understand what this is about, I suggest you to watch this railscast. It's an old one but it explain clearly the basic principle of it http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

Then you can also read this pretty good article http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/

Once you understand the principles, have a look at [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) and [ActionController::Streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. 
I kinda chose alternative way which is the socket module with express.